# Configure HA for WILDLFY 10 artemis

Tags: wildfly-10, activemq-artemis

We have two wildlfy 10.1.0 server with the activeMq (Artemis) running. We want the two artemis to be in sync with messages. And if one is down, other one should start receiving and sending messages. There is lack of documentation in google as well as artemis is new.

Also, keeping both as active for loadbalancing., is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the internal instance of Artemis in wildfly. In the Wildfly Quickstarts, there is a good demo on Messaging Clustering. This will also work for 10.1.  It shows how to configure using Standalone-HA or Domain

https://github.com/wildfly/quickstart/tree/11.x/messaging-clustering.